# How to disable hash in filename when using jekyll-assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm new to Jekyll but so far it's really impressive. The whole asset's pipeline workflow is confusing to me though. In my `config.yaml` file I've got the following:

```
gems:
- jekyll-feed
- jekyll-assets
assets:
  autowrite: true
  prefix: "/assets"
  digest: true
  assets:
    - "*.png"
    - "*.jpg"
    - "*.svg"
  sources:
    - _assets/_img
```

All my images are in `/_assets` and so far running `bundle exec jekyll serve` copies all these files into `_site/assets/` thus rendering them at `http://127.0.0.1:4000/assets/`.

The issue is that when it copies, for example, `canlislogo.svg`, it's new filename is `canlislogo-ae5640da3ff77d178133e0ab015ef4aaa0accb025aa955c9c2aeca2ae32fbca9.svg`, adding a long hash. Since I'm using Grunt for all my Stylus css creation, I don't need this hash. In fact, with it, I have no way of referencing these files.

How can I copy the assets automatically but drop the hash?

Please and thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `digest: true` with `digest: false` should remove the hashes.

That said, I'm surprised that `asset-name` wouldn't be automatically routed to `asset-name-#{HASH}` by Jekyll?

Comment: thanks so much! this should be much clearer in their documentation.

Comment: @JeremyPaulBeasley feel free to mark this as the answer then :)